# CSS styling. Put a arrow image before a link

Tags: html, css

The link text is right aligned. I would like to place the arrow image before the link text but don't want image to be linked. I put a print-shot example in the post.

```css
#submitYourConcern {
  background: url( '/_layouts/images/grey_arrow.png' ) no-repeat right;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: #4b92db;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="submitYourConcern">
  <a href="/submit.aspx">Submit Your Concern</a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I see no reason not to make the arrow part of the link; as a user I'd intuitively expect that to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me.

```
<style>
#submitYourConcern
{
    color: #4b92db!important;
    text-align: right;
}
#submitYourConcern:before{
content: url(/_layouts/images/grey_arrow.png);
padding-right: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `::before` to place things before an element.

```css
#submitYourConcern
    {       
        background: url(/_layouts/images/grey_arrow.png) no-repeat right ;
        padding-right: 15px;
        color: #4b92db;
        text-align: right;
    }
#submitYourConcern::before {
    content: ">";
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="submitYourConcern">
<a href="/submit.aspx">Submit Your Concern</a>
</div>
```

If you want to use an image, you can use `background-image`

Comment: When using the `background-image`, you want to set `content: ""` and set the `width` and `height` properties to the size of the image.

Comment: Alternatively, assign the `background-image` to the `::before` instead.

Comment: @Blazemonger That's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

Create another div, put it in the concern div, set the background as the arrow, and align it where u want it.
Or use ::before for adding stuff to the front
Or use ::after for adding stuff to the back

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::after/::before` pseudo element to place things an element.

```css
#submitYourConcern::before {
    content: ">";
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="submitYourConcern">
    <a href="/submit.aspx">Submit Your Concern</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use `content` like this :

```css
    #submitYourConcern {
      padding-right: 15px;
      color: #4b92db;
    }
    #submitYourConcern::after {
      content: url('http://i742.photobucket.com/albums/xx61/wendarra/Bullets/bullet_grey_arrow.png');
    }
```

```html
    <div id="submitYourConcern">
      <a href="/submit.aspx">Submit Your Concern</a>
    </div>
```

Or use `::before` instead of `::after` if you want it in the other side.