# How to embed this img element into anchor tag element?

Tags: html, css

I have this arrow img element below.

```html
<img src="https://websvcs.utdallas.edu/shared/svg/arrow-diagonal-black.svg" alt="opens a link">
```

How should I go about in order to embed the img element into the anchor element. I would like the arrow to be on the top right of the hyperlink and to be smaller and same size as the hyperlink. Main concern is to get the arrow to be on the top right of the hyper link.

```html
      <a href="###">Test</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried just putting the image inside the `<a>`? (And adding some CSS to set the size)

Comment: plz see if this link helps you.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/43208847/3200792

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Where the  tag has position: relative; and the  tag is inside that with a position: absolute;

```css
body {
  padding: 3rem;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
Link Text
<img src="https://websvcs.utdallas.edu/shared/svg/arrow-diagonal-black.svg" />
</a>
```